# Ruby on rails - handle error when pulling facebook data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

Preface this with the "i'm a newbie to ruby and programming" clause.

I've managed to get the login system detailed in ruby.railstutorial.org to work and have added omniauth. This all functions so that I can create a user with either.

I'm now attempting to pull more info from Facebook and have managed to pull location amongst other things.

I am running into a problem when a Facebook user does not have a location specified yet (and I imagine I will have a similar problem if the user lacks other data I'm pulling (i.e. gender, or birthday).

I tried to catch this error like this:

```
if auth_hash["extra"]["raw_info"]["location"]["name"] 
        citystate1 = auth_hash["extra"]["raw_info"]["location"]["name"].split(',')
      else
        citystate1 =[nil,nil]
      end
```

I get the error: **undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass**

My goal is to pull whatever data is available from Facebook... if it is not available, a nil value will have to suffice.

```
user = User.new :firstname => auth_hash["info"]["first_name"],
                      :lastname => auth_hash["info"]["last_name"], 
                      :email => auth_hash["info"]["email"].downcase,
                      :dob => Date.strptime(auth_hash["extra"]["raw_info"]["birthday"],'%m/%d/%Y'),
                      :city => citystate1[0],
                      :state => citystate1[1],
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
city, state = auth_hash["extra"]["raw_info"]["location"]["name"]
  .split(',') rescue [nil, nil]
```

Comment: This worked perfectly replacing that entire "if block".  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can `fetch` the value from the hash like this:

```
%w(extra raw_info location name).inject{ |k| auth_hash.fetch(k, "there's nothing here") }
```

This will loop through the array of keys until it returns the value or can't find the key. `fetch` includes a default option - you probably want to return `nil` in place of `"there's nothing here"`

see: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-fetch